# Increase the size of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I increase the size of radio button?

I know there are many such questions, I went through the answers and tried implementing them, but nothing worked.

Following are among some links that I tried.

[change size of radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837972/change-size-of-radio-buttons)

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Can anyone please suggest me a working example. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630314/resizing-radio-button

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920281/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-radio-button-using-css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont want to change the *scale*, you can use CSS to create custom styling (checkbox used as an example). The advantage is you then arent limited to the browser specific look and feel of the control.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/MvTB6/3/)

HTML

```
<input type='checkbox' />
```

CSS

```
input[type=checkbox]{
    position:relative;
    margin:5px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:before{
    position:absolute;
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    top:-5px;
    left:-5px;
    border:2px solid grey;
    content:'';
    background:white;
    border-radius:100%;
}
input[type=checkbox]:after{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    height:15px;
    width:15px;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
    content:'';
    background:grey;
    border-radius:100%;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked:after{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres a very basic example : http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/uu47Z/

Html

```
<form action="/html/codes/html_form_handler.cfm" method="get">
<input type="radio" name="preferred_color" value="Red" class="red" /> Red<br />
<input type="radio" name="preferred_color" value="Blue" /> Blue<br />
<input type="radio" name="preferred_color" value="Green" /> Green<br />
</form>
```

Css

```
input[type=radio] {
    margin: 1em 1em 1em 0;
    transform: scale(3, 3);
    -moz-transform: scale(3, 3);
    -ms-transform: scale(3, 3);
    -webkit-transform: scale(3, 3);
    -o-transform: scale(3, 3);
}
```

Produces

[image]

Comment: +1 This would be my choice if you wish to have the same style

Comment: This is a good choice if you want to avoid JS intervention, However the render is awful (at least on my mac/chrome), radio buttons are very pixelised

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the CSS zoom feature.

```css
h1 {
  zoom:200%
}
```

```html
<h1><input type="radio"></h1>
```